# Mark all universities on google map using google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a web based project and I want to show a map where I can show user's location and mark universities around him/her. I have no experience on google map javascript api. I also search on google but cannot found reliable result. I tried it but couldn't make some logic. so please give me solution.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to know the lat/lng of each university.
In a mobile app (android, ios...), you can get the actual location (lat/lng) from the gps,
after, you should use a algorithm that calculates in meters or miles the distance between two lat/lng points and determine if it will be shown or not.